# Sharing Rules for Activities

Tags: sharing, activities, sharing-rule

Why can't I set sharing rules for Activities. I am trying to enforce a rule that only a certain role (or profile if thats what I have to do) can view an activity. For example I want any activity completed by an Inside Sales rep to be viewed by other Inside Sales Reps, inside Sales Managers, and System Admins but not to Outside Reps. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the OWD set to public read/write?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have tried on both Private and Controlled by Parent. I am guessing there is some correlation?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to share *any* object whose visibility is controlled by parent nor public read/write. You cannot restrict visibility, only increase it.

Comment: but you would expect it to work if it was on Private?

Comment: You can't create sharing rules for activities at all regardless of the sharing model. Sharing for activities is either controlled by the parent or private. Even if it's private, sharing rules aren't supported. There's an idea for it if you want to upvote but it's 10 years old and Salesforce has no plans to implement: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrFmAAK

Comment: @JohnTowers thanks for sharing I reached out to my rep with an angry email. Typical from them they sold to that specific feature. Thanks

Comment: Should the inside sales reps & managers NOT be allowed to view the records (e.g. Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, or Leads) that the Activities are logged under?  Do you want them to see activities for e.g. an account but no information about the account?  I'm trying to understand a use case for sharing activity details but no details about the subject of the activities